# Subtracting a column value from the same column but a previous date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Main problem - I need to subtract a previous pay period total of Column A from a current pay period total column A. The column is a rolling total of an employee's Earned PTO hours, and I need to get the hours earned for the current pay period rather than the running total.

The attempt below is using #TempTable, it is telling me there is a syntax error at the very end but I haven't been able to find the problem. I have also tried using CTE's but I've read that temp tables are more efficient.

Any ideas? thanks in advance!

```
    USE DatahubProd

    BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMPa
    ;

    SELECT * INTO #TEMPa FROM (SELECT
    p.employmentStatus AS RelationshipStatus,
    p.personNumber,
    p.hourlyRate AS PayRate,
    CASE
        WHEN p.fullTimeEquivalencyPercent = 100 THEN 'Full Time'
        ELSE 'Part Time'
    END AS WorkType,
    p.hireDate,
    CASE
        WHEN p.employmentStatus NOT IN ('Active', 'Inactive') THEN CAST(p.updateDtm AS date)
        ELSE '01-01-1900'
    END AS terminationDate,
    p.fullName,
    LEFT(abs1.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak2,2) AS Entity,
    RIGHT(abs1.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak3,4) AS Division,
    LEFT(abs1.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak4,3) AS Location,
    abs1.Acc_AccrualCodeId AS AccrualCodeId,
    abs1.Acc_AccrualCode AS AccrualCode,
    abs1.Date_BalanceAsOfDate as 'PayPeriodEndDate',
    p.snapShotDate AS EffectiveDate,
    CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(abs1.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak3,4) IN (8087,8301,8302,8303,8304,8305,8306,8307) THEN (abs1.M_Acc_EarnedToDate_Hrs)
        ELSE 0
    END AS ICSHours,
    CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(abs1.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak3,4) IN (8087,8301,8302,8303,8304,8305,8306,8307) THEN (p.hourlyRate  * abs1.M_Acc_EarnedToDate_Hrs)
        ELSE 0
    END AS ICSLiability,
    CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(abs1.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak3,4) NOT IN (8087,8301,8302,8303,8304,8305,8306,8307) THEN (abs1.M_Acc_EarnedToDate_Hrs)  
        ELSE 0
    END AS CMHHours,
    CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(abs1.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak3,4) NOT IN (8087,8301,8302,8303,8304,8305,8306,8307) THEN (p.hourlyRate  * abs1.M_Acc_EarnedToDate_Hrs)
        ELSE 0
    END AS CMHLiability
    FROM [DatahubProd].[dbo].[vw_vPeople] p
    INNER JOIN [DatahubProd].[dbo].[vw_vAccrualBalanceSummary] abs1 ON p.personId = abs1.Person_personId
    WHERE p.employmentStatus IN ('Active', 'Inactive', 'Terminated') AND abs1.Acc_AccrualCodeId = 12 AND abs1.Date_BalanceAsOfDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -19, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND DATEADD(DAY, -14, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    GROUP BY 
    p.personNumber,
    p.employmentStatus,
    p.hourlyRate,
    p.hireDate,
    p.fullName,
    abs1.Acc_AccrualCodeId,
    abs1.Acc_AccrualCode,
    p.snapShotDate,
    p.fullTimeEquivalencyPercent,
    abs1.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak2,
    abs1.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak3,
    abs1.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak4,
    p.updateDtm,
    abs1.M_Acc_CurrentBalVested_Hrs,
    abs1.M_Acc_EarnedToDate_Hrs,
    abs1.Date_BalanceAsOfDate) a;
    
    SELECT
    p.employmentStatus AS RelationshipStatus,
    p.personNumber AS EmployeeId,
    p.hourlyRate AS PayRate,
    CASE
        WHEN p.fullTimeEquivalencyPercent = 100 THEN 'Full Time'
        ELSE 'Part Time'
    END AS WorkType,
    p.hireDate,
    CASE
        WHEN p.employmentStatus NOT IN ('Active', 'Inactive') THEN CAST(p.updateDtm AS date)
        ELSE '01-01-1900'
    END AS terminationDate,
    p.fullName,
    LEFT(abs2.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak2,2) AS Entity,
    RIGHT(abs2.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak3,4) AS Division,
    LEFT(abs2.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak4,3) AS Location,
    abs2.Acc_AccrualCodeId AS AccrualCodeId,
    abs2.Acc_AccrualCode AS AccrualCode,
    abs2.Date_BalanceAsOfDate as 'PayPeriodEndDate',
    p.snapShotDate AS EffectiveDate,
    CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(abs2.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak3,4) IN (8087,8301,8302,8303,8304,8305,8306,8307) THEN (abs2.M_Acc_EarnedToDate_Hrs - a.ICSHours)
        ELSE 0
    END AS ICSHours,
    CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(abs2.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak3,4) IN (8087,8301,8302,8303,8304,8305,8306,8307) THEN (p.hourlyRate  * (abs2.M_Acc_EarnedToDate_Hrs-a.ICSHours))
        ELSE 0
    END AS ICSLiability,
    CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(abs2.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak3,4) NOT IN (8087,8301,8302,8303,8304,8305,8306,8307) THEN (abs2.M_Acc_EarnedToDate_Hrs-a.ICSHours)   
        ELSE 0
    END AS CMHHours,
    CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(abs2.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak3,4) NOT IN (8087,8301,8302,8303,8304,8305,8306,8307) THEN (p.hourlyRate  * (abs2.M_Acc_EarnedToDate_Hrs-a.ICSHours))
        ELSE 0
    END AS CMHLiability
    FROM [DatahubProd].[dbo].[vw_vPeople] p
    INNER JOIN [DatahubProd].[dbo].[vw_vAccrualBalanceSummary] abs2 ON p.personId = abs2.Person_personId
    INNER JOIN #TEMPa a ON p.personNumber = a.personNumber
    WHERE p.employmentStatus IN ('Active', 'Inactive', 'Terminated') AND abs2.Acc_AccrualCodeId = 12 AND abs2.Date_BalanceAsOfDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 4, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND DATEADD(DAY, 0, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    GROUP BY 
    p.personNumber,
    p.employmentStatus,
    p.hourlyRate,
    p.hireDate,
    p.fullName,
    abs2.Acc_AccrualCodeId,
    abs2.Acc_AccrualCode,
    p.snapShotDate,
    p.fullTimeEquivalencyPercent,
    abs2.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak2,
    abs2.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak3,
    abs2.BusPri_primaryOrgBreak4,
    p.updateDtm,
    abs2.M_Acc_CurrentBalVested_Hrs,
    abs2.M_Acc_EarnedToDate_Hrs,
    abs2.Date_BalanceAsOfDate
```

Comment: 1) Don't use images for data, use table markdown. 2) Provide a complete [mre] with sample date, desired results and your attempt... emphasis on *minimal* i.e. remove everything not relevant to the problem at hand so we can clearly see the issue you are facing without having to wade through your production code.

Comment: You really need to include the actual error message that you're receiving.

Comment: Temp tables are `sometimes` more efficient then CTEs, it depends on the query. You should try both and see which is faster.

Comment: Have you taken a look at LAG function? It allows accessing previous value in a query